# Where are the main azerothcore folder with docker?

Tags: git, docker, azerothcore

Hi :) I just reinstalled azerothcore from scratch with the new install method with docker, and it has certainly been fast and works flawlessly.

But now I find myself with the problem that I don't know which is the main folder to insert git commands (git log, git checkout, git pull, etc)

I have tried in all the appdata folders related to docker, as well as in program files, and obviously in the main one of AC, no luck for now.

Thanks in advance and greetings.

Comment: it's the main directory, the one you download with the `git clone` , typically called `azerothcore-wotlk`

Comment: I thought so, but the git commands there do not work

Comment: did you clone it with git or downloaded it as a zip archive?

Comment: yep the guys helped me to find it out and seems that was exactly that :D, result of downloading it

Answer (score 0):

Git commands do not work if you download the zip archive instead of cloning the repo using git:

```
git clone git@github.com:azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk.git
```

Comment: Thanks, one of these days i'll reinstall all again so ^^!!